# RelativeLayout : Is it possible to replace the value in "dp" by a unit relative to the screen size?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio, android-relativelayout

I need a unit of measure that is relative to the screen size.
My goal is that the checkbox position remain relatively the same place on several screens.
I am working with several checkboxs and no layout can express better than RelativeLayout the interface I desire.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <RelativeLayout
     android:screenOrientation="landscape"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="39dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:id="@+id/aae"
        android:background="@drawable/aae"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="185dp"
        android:checked="false"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

It is possible to replace the value in "dp" by a unit relative to the screen size?

```
android:layout_width="39dp"
android:layout_height="32dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
android:layout_marginTop="185dp"
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [resource qualifiers](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#qualifiers) to have multiple values for the DP depending on the screen size or density.

This would allow you to have:
`<dimen name="width">39dp</dimen>` in values/dimens.xml
and
`<dimen name="width">10dp</dimen>` in values-mdpi/dimens.xml

The above would allow you set the width to 10dp on medium density devices and 39dp on everything above medium.

Alternatively you could use the new [PercentRelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout.html) that's available in the support lib.

Make sure to add `compile "com.android.support:percent:23.1.1"` to your app modules build.gradle

Comment: The PercentRelativeLayout is compliant with any API below 23?

Comment: @kawai Yeah the percent support lib works for any Android version